# Joining hive and mysql tables

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive

I have a table in MySQL and another table is in hive. Without importing MYSQL table to hive, is there any way to join both tables and get the result...

```
SELECT ua.address_id
FROM mysqltable u
inner join hivetable ua on ua.address_id = u.user_address_id
WHERE u.user_id = 123;
```

Comment: You might want to look at PrestoDB, or at the very least, you need to Sqoop the table into Hive

Comment: Checked PrestoDB. I should have HIVE in PrestoDB or MYSQL in PrestoDB?? I have installed and running the Presto Server in my system. Not sure how to use it. Please give me some hint what to do there and how to connect both DBs...

Comment: There's things called connectors and catalogs that you must configure. Then you can select and join from other databases. https://prestodb.io/docs/current/connector.html